# How to make Java Int Array show in Desending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Right now this code shows in Ascending order of chance value, highest rarity showing first such as 1/2 and and lower chance rarity such as 1/20 is showing last on list . How can i make it show 1/20 chance/rarity in the beginning of the list?
for example, currentlty this list shows, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, but i want it to show 1/4, 1/3, 1/2 ?

this is my display code

```java
public static void display(Player player, NPCDrops definition) {
          int j = 0;
        player.getPacketSender().sendFrame126(37602, NpcDefinition.forId(definition.getNpcIds()[0]).getName()+" - Drops");
        j++;
        player.getPacketSender().sendInterface(37600);
      
        for (int i = 0; i < 70 - j; i++) {
            player.getPacketSender().sendString(ITEM_STRING+i, "");
            player.getPacketSender().sendString(AMOUNT_STRING+i, "");
            player.getPacketSender().sendString(RARITY_STRING+i, "");
        }
        List<Item> drop = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0;
        
        List<NPCDrops.NpcDropItem> dropList = Arrays.asList(definition.getDropList());

        dropList.sort(Comparator.comparing(NPCDrops.NpcDropItem::getChance));

        for(NPCDrops.NpcDropItem item : dropList) {
            ItemDefinition itemDef = ItemDefinition.forId(item.getId());
            if(index > 69 || itemDef == null|| itemDef.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("none"))
                continue;

            drop.add(item.getItem());
            index++;
            player.getPacketSender().sendString(ITEM_STRING+index, itemDef.getName());
            player.getPacketSender().sendString(AMOUNT_STRING+index, item.getCount()[0]+"");
            player.getPacketSender().sendString(RARITY_STRING+index, item.getChance().getRandom() == 0 ? "Always" : "1/"+item.getChance().getRandom()+"");

        }
        player.getPacketSender().sendItemsOnInterface(37915, 70, drop, true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort your objects with a comparator.

```
dropList.sort(Comparator.comparing(NPCDrops.NpcDropItem::getChance));
```

Luckily the interface does also provide a reversed method.

```
dropList.sort(Comparator.comparing(NPCDrops.NpcDropItem::getChance).reversed());
```